# Nanoc changing the base path when deploying page in github

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, github, nanoc, github-pages

I have a simple static page app that i have built with nanoc and i want to deploy it as a github page.

Everything goes well except that the assets (like css, javascripts) and all the links in general point to the root of the repo:

like

> /css/style.css

instead of being

> /docs/css/style.css

Everything works well on localhost but fails when published.

i am using rake publish to push it to gh-pages.

Here is my Rakefile

```
require 'nanoc3/tasks'

BASE_URL = "http://darko1002001.github.com/docs/"

desc "Compile the site"
task :compile do
  `nanoc compile`
end

desc "Publish to http://documentation.getchute.com"
task :publish => [:clean] do
  FileUtils.rm_r('output') if File.exist?('output')

  sh "nanoc compile"

  ENV['GIT_DIR'] = File.expand_path(`git rev-parse --git-dir`.chomp)
  old_sha = `git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/gh-pages`.chomp
  Dir.chdir('output') do
    ENV['GIT_INDEX_FILE'] = gif = '/tmp/dev.gh.i'
    ENV['GIT_WORK_TREE'] = Dir.pwd
    File.unlink(gif) if File.file?(gif)
    `git add -A`
    tsha = `git write-tree`.strip
    puts "Created tree   #{tsha}"
    if old_sha.size == 40
      csha = `echo 'boom' | git commit-tree #{tsha} -p #{old_sha}`.strip
    else
      csha = `echo 'boom' | git commit-tree #{tsha}`.strip
    end
    puts "Created commit #{csha}"
    puts `git show #{csha} --stat`
    puts "Updating gh-pages from #{old_sha}"
    `git update-ref refs/heads/gh-pages #{csha}`
    `git push origin gh-pages`
  end
end
```

Rules

```
compile '/static/*' do
end

compile '/CNAME/' do
end

compile '/feed/' do
  filter :erb
  filter :kramdown, :toc_levels => [2]
end

%w(v3 */).each do |version|
  compile "/changes/#{version}" do
    filter :erb
    filter :kramdown, :toc_levels => [2]
    filter :colorize_syntax,
      :colorizers => {:javascript => :pygmentsrb}
    layout 'changes' if version[0] == '*'
    layout 'default'
  end
end

compile '*' do
  filter :erb
  filter :kramdown, :toc_levels => [2]
  filter :colorize_syntax,
    :colorizers => {:javascript => :pygmentsrb}
  layout 'default'
end

route '/static/*' do
  item.identifier[7..-2]
end

route '/CNAME/' do
  '/CNAME'
end

route '/feed' do
  '/changes.atom'
end

route '*' do
  item.identifier + 'index.html'
end

layout '*', :erb
```

Comment: You might want to use ``` route '/static/*/' item.identifier.gsub(/\/static\//, '/').chop ``` so that if you change the name of the folder you remember to update the string change.

Answer (score 6):

nanoc generates absolute URLs by default, but you can use the `relativize_paths` filter to make all URLs relative. For HTML, use `filter :relativize_paths, :type => :html`. For CSS, use `:css` instead of `:html`.

Cheers

Denis

Comment: hey denis. here is how the src is generated. <img src="/images/logo_developer.png" width="100" height="45" alt="">. So i think this is a relative path right?

Comment: A path is absolute if it starts with a slash. "/images/logo_developer.png" is absolute so it is resolved to http://example.com/images/logo_developer.png instead of http://example.com/docs/images/logo_developer.png. If you run the `relativize_paths` filter, that path will be relative, so it will be e.g. "../images/logo_developer.png" depending on where it is referenced from. This way, you can build a site and be able to put it in any subdirectory you want--even move it to a different location without having to recompile.

Comment: So how do i change this to have relative paths. i haven't been able to find any good examples of doing it...

Comment: The answer to that question is in my answer. Use the `relativize_paths` filter to relativize paths in HTML and CSS.

Comment: An example can be found at https://github.com/lifepillar/nanoc4-template/blob/master/Rules