# Nanoc setup for URLs and links on a github deployed webpage

Tags: html, github, github-pages, nanoc

I depoyed a static webpage on github with nanoc. Everything works very nice.
Except that the images not their thumbnails are visible. The URL path is missing the project name. So when i click in the image caption i get redirected to:

```
https://<username>.github.io/assets/images/test.jpg
```

instead of:

```
https://<username>.github.io/<project_name>/assets/images/test.jpg
```

The html source looks like:

```
<a target="_blank" href="/assets/images/test.jpg">
 <img src="/assets/images/test.jpg" alt="test" width="500" height="400">
</a>
```

With this setup it is working on my local machine. So with ´nanoc view´ the page with its images is visible at the localhost. 
The file structure does not include the project name, so how is it possible for the deployment env to add the project name to the path?

The same happens also with the links in the menu. When i click on a link i get redirected to

```
https://<username>.github.io/about
```

instead of:

```
https://<username>.github.io/<projectname>/about/
```

Thanks to everybody in advance!

Comment: I guess [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13513857/1591669) should solve your problem. If yes, we can close your question as duplicate.